# Como alinhar todos os elementos de um form no centro?

Tags: css

Estou tentando alinhar os elementos de um form no centro e deixar a tag **label** na parte esquerda dos campos, desta forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
<form>
    <label for="info">Seu Texto</label>
                <textarea id="info"></textarea>

                <label for="cat">Seu Texto</label>

                <select class="selectpicker" id="cat">
                    <option>Mustard</option>
                    <option>Ketchup</option>
                    <option>Relish</option>
                </select>
```

CSS:

```
form {
    width: 700px;
    color: red;
}
form label {
    color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
}
form textarea, input, select {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: none;
    background: #DDDDDD;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

form textarea {
    width: 625px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 212px;
}
form select {
    width: 625px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
}
```

O form possui está dentro de uma div de 700px, o tamanho dele tbm é 700px. como posso alinhar os elementos **(inputs,textareas, selects)** e deixar os **labels** na parte esquerda superior?

Answer (score 0):

Coloque nos campos que quer centralizar:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Dê uma olhada no exemplo:
[» **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rz08cxg6/)